# What operations on bound properties need to be done on UI thread?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0

I am planning to introduce threading in my WPF application. I know that any operation on ObservableCollection (like add and remove) needs to be done on a UI thread.

But can I change the value of a property of a bound object present inside the ObservableCollection / bound to the UI on a background thread?

Comment: Good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980642/why-isnt-it-possible-to-update-an-observablecollection-from-a-different-thread

Comment: @sa_ddam213 The post talks about ObservableCollections. Can I update property values from non UI threads?

Comment: You can; the binding engine takes care of invoking the code that updates the bound properties on the UI thread. You can also try it yourself and see that it works.