# WPF MVVM Updating UI Bound properties from BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Are there any potential issues with updating UI bound properties of the ViewModel from the Backgroundworker? I am trying to update the VM while it is bound to the UI, and potentially users might be typing in.. how does the the synchronization work here (I don't think I can use Lock statements from XAML).

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When updating scalar properties, you don't need to worry about doing it on the UI thread. The `PropertyChanged` event is automatically marshalled to the UI thread.

However, it **won't work** for collections that implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`. The `CollectionChanged` event won't be marshalled to the UI thread, and it will cause an exception. So if you modify a collection that is bound to an `ItemsControl`, you need to use `Dispatcher.Invoke` (or another synchronization mechanism) to do it on the UI thread. Another option is to use a specialized collection that takes care of marshalling the event to the correct thread. See [this article](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/04/17/wpf-binding-to-an-asynchronous-collection/) for an example of such a collection.

Comment: I am Using Josh Einstein's (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091988/how-do-i-update-an-observablecollection-via-a-worker-thread) AddOnUI for updating collections. But i am mainly concerned about <Model> object property in the MVVM which in turn feeds other properties of the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience with Silverlight, trying to do so will cause an exception anyway.

Basically you need to update the bound properties from the dispatcher thread, just as if you were modifying the UI directly.

In order to allow the ViewModel to do that without knowing about a real `Dispatcher`, I've found it useful to create an `IDispatcher` interface, then use a `SameThreadDispatcher` for tests and a `SystemDispatcher` (which delegates to the real thing) for production. You then pass the ViewModel the `IDispatcher` as a dependency.

Comment: I don't know about Silverlight, but in WPF you *can* update ViewModel properties from a worker thread without problems, but collections have to be modified on the UI thread... (see my answer for details)