# Adding items to ObservableCollection from ThreadPool

Tags: c#, multithreading

My question is quite simple I have a class which contains a (private) object of type `ObservableCollection<T>` and now I'd like to run some threads (in sequence, thus the `ThreadPool` and not `BackgroundWorkers`) which add new items to the `ObservableCollection<T>`.

If the `ObservableCollection<T>` would be, let's say, a `ProgressBar`, all would be quite easy (-> Invoke) but I have no idea how to invoke the `ObservableCollection<T>` object.

My goal is to have something like a `BackgroundWorker` which can be run sequence.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend using `Task` objects for the background operations and queueing updates to the UI thread using `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`.

Comment: I took a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997394.aspx#Y500 but this describes how to use tasks in parallel, how can I "dynamically" generate a new task (i.e. on each button click) and put them in the queue?

Comment: `Task.Factory.StartNew` creates a new task. Remember that there are two tasks involved: one doing the background operation and another one doing the actual update to the `ObservableCollection`; only the "update" task should use the `TaskScheduler`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you want to add a StatusItem item to an observable collection.  In the .cs file of the user control, you might declare it like this:

```
ObservableCollection<StatusItem> _listStatus = 
       new ObservableCollection<StatusItem>();
```

You can then declare a method to add items like so:

```
private void AddStatus(StatusItem item, bool useDispatcher)
{
    if (useDispatcher) {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, 
           new ThreadStart(() => AddStatus(item, false)));
        return;
    }

    if (_listStatus.Count > MaxItemsToHoldInList) {
        // maybe you have a more efficient way to do this
        for (int i = 0; i < BlockOfItems; i++ ) _listStatus.RemoveAt(0);
    }

    _listStatus.Add(item);

    if (_scrollIntoView) listStatus.ScrollIntoView(item);
}
```

I've taken a few liberties, so maybe you don't need all of this.  Basically, if you want to call this method from inside a worker thread, you must use the dispatcher to postpone your modification until it hits the user thread (which sounds like what you want to do).  You probably already figured out that if you weren't using a dispatcher thread that your updates weren't making it to the GUI.  Of course, if you are actively in the user thread (responding to a mouse click, for instance), you can set `useDispatcher = false` when you call this method.

I personally use observable collections a lot for feedback to the user, and so, in my case, I limit the window that the user will be able to see.  Removing items a bundle at a time is for performance when you are really zinging those status messages out.  I also check to see if the user dropped the thumb at the bottom of the list control on which these items are shown.  If they did, then I set `_scrollIntoView` to true to keep the bottom-most item in view.

Comment: Now this is quite interesting, I'll try it after supper.

Comment: Yeah, it's easy, but honestly, @Stephen Cleary's solution looks more in line with the times and works cleanly across both WPF and WinForms.

Comment: yeah I'm taking a look at it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You can safely synchronize access to the collection like this:

```
lock (myCollection) {
    myCollection.InsertItem(0, myItem);
}
```

Only one thread can modify the collection at a time.  Be sure to place any code using the collection inside of the lock block.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really do this without creating your own collection class. [How do I update an ObservableCollection via a worker thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091988/how-do-i-update-an-observablecollection-via-a-worker-thread)

There are some implementations of thread-safe observabler collections available : http://www.deanchalk.me.uk/post/Thread-Safe-Dispatcher-Safe-Observable-Collection-for-WPF.aspx

Comment: Yeah I already took a look at those thread-safe observable collections, but there were some problems (either with my usage or with the implementation) if all else fails, I'll try harder with one of those.