# ObservableCollection not thread-safe even in .NET 4.5?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am banging my head against the virtual wall for days now.
The BindingOperations.EnableSynchronization method seems to work only partial in .NET 4.5.

I wrote a test that fails sometimes:

```
        object blah = new object();

        Application app = Application.Current == null ? new Application() : Application.Current;
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());
        ObservableCollection<ThreadSafeObservableTestObject> collection = null;
        collection = new ObservableCollection<ThreadSafeObservableTestObject>();

        BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(collection, blah);

        CollectionTestWindow w = new CollectionTestWindow();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            w.TestCollection = collection;
            collection.CollectionChanged += collection_CollectionChanged;
            collection.Add(new ThreadSafeObservableTestObject() { ID = 1, Name = "Sandra Bullock" });
            collection.Add(new ThreadSafeObservableTestObject() { ID = 2, Name = "Jennifer Aniston" });
            collection.Add(new ThreadSafeObservableTestObject() { ID = 3, Name = "Jennifer Lopez" });
            collection.Add(new ThreadSafeObservableTestObject() { ID = 4, Name = "Angelina Jolie" });
            collection.Add(new ThreadSafeObservableTestObject() { ID = 5, Name = "Mary Elizabeth Mastrantonio" });
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => w.Close());
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Application.Current.Shutdown());
        });
        app.Run(w);
```

The TestCollectionWindow looks like this:

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TestCollection}" Name="list">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

So nothing magic here. But the result is almost every time that some entries are twice in the UI - the same objects!
The result window looks like this then:

> Sandra Bullock 1
>   Jennifer Aniston 2
>   Jennifer Lopez 3
>   Angelina Jolie 4
>   Mary Elizabeth Mastrantonio 5
>   Jennifer Aniston 2

As you can clearly see Jennifer Aniston is listed twice. This can be reproduced easily. 
Is this a general problem or is there anything wrong with this test, such as a flawed application instantiation?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Most collection classes are not thread safe and never will be.   Thread safety is **hard**, and requires different APIs.  Look at the concurrent collections.

Comment: Maybe you should check the namespace [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx).

Comment: Try this collection which takes care of this problem as well as other multi-threaded problems that will inevitably crop up with other approaches : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/64936/Multithreaded-ObservableImmutableCollection

Answer (score 16):

The class is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) to not be thread-safe:

> **Thread Safety**
>   Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

So no, it is not thread-safe.

Note that [BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh198845.aspx) does not magically make the entire collection thread-safe. It only tells the binding system which locking object that you intend to use in order to prevent multiple threads accessing the collection at the same time.

Since you're not actually using the locking object, you might as well not call that method, the results will be equally unpredictable.

Try issuing a `lock` on the `blah` object around each statement that accesses the collection. Unfortunately the details around data binding in WPF is unknown to me, so I have no idea if that is enough.

Comment: Using `lock(){}` won't work because the other thread is the GUI.

Comment: I thought that was the point of the EnableCollectionSynchronization method, to tell the binding system (GUI) that it needs to synchronize on the lock object, but as I said, I'm no expert on this.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - per the documentation, using `lock(){}` is exactly what you *are* supposed to do, when using `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` variant that takes a lock object parameter. Why do you say this "won't work"? Of course it becomes programmer's responsibility to `lock()` around only quick snippets of code, to avoid causing laggy UI. E.g. do all the prep work, and *then* lock just an `Add` call. Or if need to foreach some expensive code, lock while making a copy of the collection, then do the expensive code on the copy.

Comment: Agreeing with ToolmakerSteve. This is the way to go without over-engineering the whole process.

Answer (score 9):

I recently needed to solve this issue as well and wrote about my solution on CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/998619/Thread-Safe-ObservableCollection-T

The solution involved using a [SyncronizationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to invoke the event handlers on the UI thread and a [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to ensure only one write occurred at a time and that no writes occurred during a read.

Full source code is available at the CodeProject link above but here's some snippets:

```
public SynchronizedObservableCollection()
{
    _context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
}

private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var collectionChanged = CollectionChanged;
    if (collectionChanged == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    using (BlockReentrancy())
    {
        _context.Send(state => collectionChanged(this, e), null);
    }
}

public bool Contains(T item)
{
    _itemsLock.EnterReadLock();

    try
    {
        return _items.Contains(item);
    }
    finally
    {
        _itemsLock.ExitReadLock();
    }
}

public void Add(T item)
{
    _itemsLock.EnterWriteLock();

    var index = _items.Count;

    try
    {
        CheckIsReadOnly();
        CheckReentrancy();

        _items.Insert(index, item);
    }
    finally
    {
        _itemsLock.ExitWriteLock();
    }

    OnPropertyChanged("Count");
    OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
    OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, index);
}
```

Comment: Read your Code Project article, and I must say it's excellent work!

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using .Net 4.5, you can use the Thread-safe collections, ConcurrentDictionary, ConcurrentBag etc, whichever suits your needs : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx

This article may also help : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/208361/Concurrent-Observable-Collection-Dictionary-and-So

Comment: The codeproject link seems to be helpful, I will take a look there.

Comment: Actually that codeproject collection isn't thread-safe either. Try http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/64936/Multithreaded-ObservableImmutableCollection

Comment: See my answer for another alternative solution also posted to CodeProject

Comment: @Anthony Id use that if it didnt force a System.Collections.Immutable dependency.