# Adding item to ObsercableCollection with ICollectionView for filtering WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I have a MainViewModel and a CategoryViewModel

MainViewmodel has the collection:

```
 public ObservableCollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
```

Inside CategoryViewModel I have the ICollectionView for filtering:

```
    public ICollectionView CategoriesView { get; set; }

CategoriesView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_mainViewModel.Categories );
                CategoriesView .Filter = new Predicate<object>(o => Filter(o as Category));
```

The thing is that if I don't use CategoriesView I can modify (add, edit, remove) my Categories ObservableCollection, but when I implement the CategoriesView for filtering, I get a NotSupportedException when trying to add a new Category to the ObservableCollection:

*This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread*

I already tried  [This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331723/this-type-of-collectionview-does-not-support-changes-to-its-sourcecollection-fro)

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
            {
                _mainViewModel.Categories.Add(newCategory);
            });
```

Also:

```
BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(_matchObsCollection , _lock);
```

I already went to Debug --> Windows --> Threads
The method is indeed in the Main Thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like

```
CategoriesView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_mainViewModel.Categories );
            CategoriesView .Filter = new Predicate<object>(o => Filter(o as Category));
```

is running on a non-ui thread. Try to run it by **Dispatcher.Invoke** to ensure it run on main-ui thread :

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
        {
            CategoriesView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_mainViewModel.Categories );
            CategoriesView .Filter = new Predicate<object>(o => Filter(o as Category));
        });
```

I found a similar case in another post you may refer to it : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ba22092e-ddb5-4cf9-95e3-8ecd61b0468d/listview-not-updating-white-copying-files-in-different-thread?forum=wpf

Comment: That's it! My mistake, I wasn't declaring it in the main thread... Thanks!