# WPF: This type of CollectionView does not support changes error

Tags: wpf, multithreading, forms, log4net

So I have `WPF` application and I want to add Logger `form`.

So I create another `form`:

```
public partial class LoggerForm : MetroWindow
{
    public LoggerForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = LogHelper.LogEntries;
        lvLogger.ItemsSource = LogHelper.LogEntries;
    }

    public void AddRandomEntry(LogEntry logEntry)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => LogHelper.LogEntries.Add(logEntry)));
    }
}
```

XAML `ListView`:

```
<ListView Name="lvLogger"
          Background="#181818"
          Margin="0,0,0,0">
<ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Time" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DateTime}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Index" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Index}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Level" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Level}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Source" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Source}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Message" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Message}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Log `object`:

```
public class LogEntry
{
    public string DateTime { get; set; }

    public int Index { get; set; }

    public string Source{ get; set; }

    public Level Level { get; set; }        

    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

List:

```
public class LogHelper
{
    public static ObservableCollection<LogEntry> LogEntries { get; set; }
}
```

So this is how I add log into my List:

Open my Logger `form`:

```
Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    // Create and show the Window
    loggerForm = new LoggerForm();
    loggerForm.Show();

    // Start the Dispatcher Processing
    Dispatcher.Run();
}));

// Set the apartment state.
newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
newWindowThread.Start();
```

And from my main `form` I create `LogEntry` object and I add it:

```
private void AddLog(Level level, string message)
{
    if (loggerForm != null)
    {
        LogEntry logEntry = new LogEntry()
        {
            DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff"),
            Index = LogHelper.LogEntries.Count,
            Level = level,
            Source = "bla bla",
            Message = message
        };

        loggerForm.AddRandomEntry(logEntry);
    }
}
```

So this works fine until I close the `Logger` form and open it again. At this point, if I add another `LogEntry`, I have this `error` in `AddRandomEntry` method:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'This type of CollectionView does not
>   support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from
>   the Dispatcher thread.'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331723/this-type-of-collectionview-does-not-support-changes-to-its-sourcecollection-fro)