# Failed to create App archive. This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, archiving

In Visual Studio 2017, while attempting to archive a Xamarin android project i get the following error after succesfull build:

Failed to create App archive "MyArchive". This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.

Anyone else who have seen this error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331723/this-type-of-collectionview-does-not-support-changes-to-its-sourcecollection-fro

Comment: You only get this error when archiving? In somewhere in your application, you are doing manipulations that must be in the UI Thread.

Comment: Yes, I only get this error while i'm using the Build | Archive function in Visual studio. The program compiles, builds and runs vel in both debug and release mode.

Comment: in my case if check MultiDex option in compile configuration it's return to works... try and good luck

Comment: In my case restarting Visual Studio worked...

Answer (score 3):

Deleting the Bin and Obj folders also worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue.  The only way I could get around it was to uncheck "Enable Multi-Dex" in Android Options.  I think something might be broke in the latest version of visual studio 2017.

Comment: Multi-Dex is not enabled, so that's not the problem in my case. I agree, it could look as it is  a problem in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: pfff i just got this error, then just archieved again and it just worked... somethings wrong alright...

Answer (score 2):

I finally found that the solution for me, was to uninstall all the Xamarin.Android NuGet Packages from my solution, and then reinstall them.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I managed to solve it. Try removing the **Support.v7 NuGet Packages** and installing them again. Make sure to install the correct package versions as you do it. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers I'd like to add that deleting all the `bin` and `obj` folders from my project worked for me.