# Bind to ObsevableCollection not working in WINUI3 app

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, task, winui-3

I am building a semi automatic administration platform to keep track of my daytrading.
With a python script I can get information out of the platform and through a pipe it gets to the app who passes it into a `SQLite` database.

Now I'm working on getting the data out of the database and into the GUI of the application. Now, all 3 of the methods run on a `Task` thread as the pipe server is using a infinite while loop as well as the method that gets the data from the database. As the data is changing every 2 seconds it has to update the data in the GUI as well.

Binding from the xaml to the model is not working as the method is running on a different thread. This is where I'm stuck.

The code is as follows,

The first methods of the page are the `ObservableCollection` and the initialization which starts the `Task` methods with `Task.Run();` as well as the `PropertyChanged` method.

```csharp
        private ObservableCollection<OpenTradesModel> _trades = new ObservableCollection<OpenTradesModel>();
        public ObservableCollection<OpenTradesModel> Trades
        {
            get { return _trades; }
            set { _trades = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Trades)); Debug.Print("Property Changed!"); }
        }
        
        public OpenTradesView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<Task> tasks = new()
            {
                Task.Run(() => { startServerAndUseData(); }),
                Task.Run(() => { runScript(); }),
                Task.Run(() => { DataBaseQueryToGUI(); }),
            };
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

The following method gets the data from the `SQLite` database and puts it into `_trades`.

```csharp
public Task DataBaseQueryToGUI()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    using var db = new DatabaseContext();
                    var rowData = db.OpenTrades.OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();

                    foreach (var row in rowData)
                    {
                        var query = new OpenTradesModel()
                        {
                            Ticket = row.Ticket,
                            Time = row.Time,
                            Type = row.Type,
                            Magic = row.Magic,
                            Identifier = row.Identifier,
                            Reason = row.Reason,
                            Volume = row.Volume,
                            PriceOpen = row.PriceOpen,
                            StopLoss = row.StopLoss,
                            TakeProfit = row.TakeProfit,
                            CurrentPrice = row.CurrentPrice,
                            Swap = row.Swap,
                            Profit = row.Profit,
                            Symbol = row.Symbol,
                        };
                        _trades.Add(query); //This is where the exception is thrown.
                        Debug.Print("Added to Model!");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.Print(e.ToString());
                    break;
                }
               Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

The `xaml` is as follows.

```xaml
<ListView x:Name="ListData" MaxWidth="1496" Width="1496" Height="457" MaxHeight="457"
                          ItemsSource="{x:Bind Trades, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

                    <ListViewHeaderItem Margin="-11,0,0,0">
                        ...
                    </ListViewHeaderItem>

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Expander>
                                <Expander.Header>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            ...
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding Trades}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding Time}" Margin="-17,0,0,0"/>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"  Text="{Binding Type}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3"  Text="{Binding Magic}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4"  Text="{Binding Identifier}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5"  Text="{Binding Reason}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="6"  Text="{Binding Volume}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="7"  Text="{Binding PriceOpen}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="8"  Text="{Binding StopLoss}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="9"  Text="{Binding TakeProfit}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="10" Text="{Binding CurrentPrice}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="11" Text="{Binding Swap}" Margin="-15,0,0,0"/>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="12" Text="{Binding Profit}" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="13" Text="{Binding Symbol}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Expander.Header>
```

The binding seems to work but does not show the data that is put into `_trades`. As the following exception shows it has to do with threading, I just have no idea how to get the data to the UI thread. Every answer I've found here didn't work for me.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8001010E): The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))
   at WinRT.ExceptionHelpers.<ThrowExceptionForHR>g__Throw|20_0(Int32 hr)
   at WinRT.ExceptionHelpers.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 hr)
   at ABI.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Interop.WinRTNotifyCollectionChangedEventArgsRuntimeClassFactory.CreateInstanceWithAllParameters(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, IList newItems, IList oldItems, Int32 newIndex, Int32 oldIndex)
   at ABI.System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.CreateMarshaler2(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs value)
   at ABI.System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.NativeDelegateWrapper.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32 index, T item)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(T item)
   at TradeAdministration.Views.OpenTradesView.DataBaseQueryToGUI() in C:\Users\Nick\source\repos\TradeAdministration\TradeAdministration\Views\OpenTradesView.xaml.cs:line 96
```

Hopefully one of you can get me on the right track of thought. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55649038/observable-collection-multithreading and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293246/observablecollection-and-threading

Comment: Thanks, reading through them now. For the first one, Not gonna work. He uses totally different logic. The second one might work. I have to try that one as it's close to what I'm doing.

The only problem I have is both those links are questions about WPF, not WINui3 as I'm using at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the `DataBaseQueryToGUI()` function as follows:

```csharp
private async void DataBaseQueryToGUI() // Made it an async method.
        {
            await Task.Run(() => // Added
            { 
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using var db = new DatabaseContext();
                        var rowData = db.OpenTrades.OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();

                        foreach (var row in rowData)
                        {
                            var query = new OpenTradesModel()
                            {
                                Ticket = row.Ticket,
                                Time = row.Time,
                                Type = row.Type,
                                Magic = row.Magic,
                                Identifier = row.Identifier,
                                Reason = row.Reason,
                                Volume = row.Volume,
                                PriceOpen = row.PriceOpen,
                                StopLoss = row.StopLoss,
                                TakeProfit = row.TakeProfit,
                                CurrentPrice = row.CurrentPrice,
                                Swap = row.Swap,
                                Profit = row.Profit,
                                Symbol = row.Symbol,
                            };
                            this.DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() => // Pushed these to the Dispatcher.
                            {
                                _trades.Add(query);
                                Debug.Print("Added to Model!");
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Debug.Print(e.ToString());
                        break;
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }
            });
        }
```

This works for now. Although I am missing some data but that's fixable. Now I need to figure out a way to update the data instead of adding the new data.