# On Android device UI update happens only after user interaction

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, async-await, mvvmcross

Interesting (at least for me) bug I found there.

I am making an (prototype) app, it does some web requests and returns simple data.

There is `ObservableCollection<DownloadbleEntity>` which is updated dynamicly (because `DownloadbleEntity` contains the image which we get by other requests, to output list element with an image).

Here is layout part:

```
   <MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxListView
        android:id="@+id/searchlist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource FoundItems; ItemClick OnItemClickCommand; OnScrollToBottom GetNewAsyncCommand"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem" />
```

And this is the ViewModel code to show an idea of how update is going:

```
        private ObservableCollection<DownloadableEntity> _foundItems;

        public ObservableCollection<DownloadableEntity> FoundItems
        {
            get { return _foundItems; }

            set
            {
                if (_currentPage > 0)
                {
                    _foundItems = new ObservableCollection<DownloadableEntity>(_foundItems.Concat(value));
                }
                else
                {
                    _foundItems = value;
                }

                RaisePropertyChanged(() => FoundItems);
            }
        }

 private async Task PrepareDataForOutput(SearchResult searchResult)
        {
            _currentListLoaded = false;
            IMvxMainThreadDispatcher dispatcher = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMainThreadDispatcher>();
            List<Task<DownloadableEntity>> data = searchResult.Tracks.Items.ToList().Select(async (x) => await PrepareDataOutputAsync(x).ConfigureAwait(false)).ToList();
            Android.Util.Log.Verbose("ACP", "PrepareDataForOutput");

            try
            {
                var result = new ObservableCollection<DownloadableEntity>();
                while (data.Count > 0)
                {
                    var entityToAdd = await Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        Task<DownloadableEntity> taskComplete = await Task.WhenAny(data).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        data.Remove(taskComplete);
                        DownloadableEntity taskCompleteData = await taskComplete.ConfigureAwait(false);

                        await Task.Delay(500);

                        return taskCompleteData;

                    }).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    result.Add(entityToAdd);

                    // as it recommended by mvvmcross providers
                    dispatcher.RequestMainThreadAction(async () =>
                        await Task.Run(() =>
                        {
                            Android.Util.Log.Verbose("ACP", $"RequestMainThreadAction update {result.Last().Title}");
                           _toastService.ShowToastMessage($"Got {result.Last().Title}");
                            FoundItems = result;
                        }).ConfigureAwait(false)
                    );

                }

                await Task.WhenAll(data).ContinueWith((x) =>
                 {
                     Android.Util.Log.Verbose("ACP", "Output is Done");
                     _currentListLoaded = true;
                 });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Android.Util.Log.Verbose("ACP", e.Message);
            }
        }

           private async Task<DownloadableEntity> PrepareDataOutputAsync(PurpleItem x)
        {
            return new DownloadableEntity
            {
                Title = x.Title,
                ArtistName = x.Artists.Select(y => y.Name).Aggregate((cur, next) => cur + ", " + next),
                Image = await Task.Run(() => _remoteMusicDataService.DownloadCoverByUri(x.Albums.FirstOrDefault().CoverUri)).ConfigureAwait(false),
                AlbumName = x.Albums.First().Title ?? "",
                AlbumId = x.Albums.First().Id,
                TrackId = x.Id
            };
        }
```

Well, the thing is - on devices, after data output starts it outputs one list element and at the same time outputs this:

> Time  Device Name Type    PID Tag Message 12-09 13:45:22.012  Wileyfox
>   Swift 2
>   X Info    20385   mvx android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException:
>   Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its
>   views.    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6898)     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1048)   at
>   android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:19785)  at
>   android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:19785)  at
>   android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:19785)  at
>   android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:19785)  at
>   android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:19785)  at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.requestLayout(AbsListView.java:1997)   at
>   android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:840)
>     at
>   android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AbsListView.java:6380)
>     at
>   android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
>     at
>   android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)

But it continues to update my collection, so `Android.Util.Log.Verbose("ACP", $"RequestMainThreadAction update {result.Last().Title}");` toggles and I can see it in device log window.

But it all continues to render on my device screen only after I do something - touch screen or touch my `SearchView` input or rotate it.

It's kinda strange I wonder what causes it.
Is it because of I do something wrong regarding my collection update?

*I recorded the video of whats happening, so [here it is](https://youtu.be/odLvYa06ifw) (sorry for my english and accent :( )*

**UPD (regarding to last comment):**

Is the collection really being update from the background thread if update is happening inside `dispatcher.RequestMainThreadAction`?

**UPD2**

I added thread number detection, so, looks like the number is always the same

The code:

```
 // as it recommended
 dispatcher.RequestMainThreadAction(async () =>
     await Task.Run(() =>
     {
         var poolId = TaskScheduler.Current.Id;
         Android.Util.Log.Verbose("ACP THREAD INFO", $"RequestMainThreadAction update {result.Last().Title} THREAD NUMBER {poolId}");
         _toastService.ShowToastMessage($"Got {result.Last().Title} by {result.Last().ArtistName}");
         FoundItems = result;
     }).ConfigureAwait(false)
 );
```

Also in the `View` I added:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            _searchView = FindViewById<SearchView>(Resource.Id.search10);

            ViewModel.OnSearchStartEvent += ViewModel_OnSearchStartEvent;
            var poolId = TaskScheduler.Current.Id;
            Android.Util.Log.Verbose("ACP THREAD INFO", $"VIEW CREATED FROM THREAD NUMBER {poolId}");
        }
```

The output:

[image]

Also, tried this approach but no success:

```
Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity.RunOnUiThread(async () =>
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var poolId = TaskScheduler.Current.Id;
        Android.Util.Log.Verbose("ACP THREAD INFO", $"RequestMainThreadAction update {result.Last().Title} THREAD NUMBER {poolId}");
        _toastService.ShowToastMessage($"Got {result.Last().Title} by {result.Last().ArtistName}");
        FoundItems = result;
    }).ConfigureAwait(false)
);
```

**UPD3**

I found one workaround (but still not solution) - if I use `MvxObservableCollection` instead of just `ObservableCollection` for `FoundItems` - everything working as it suppose to!

If we look at this class ([MvxObservableCollection.cs](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Core/Core/ViewModels/MvxObservableCollection.cs) ) we will see that it has those functions which are triggering on updates, looks like it does the same thing there:

```
        protected virtual void InvokeOnMainThread(Action action)
        {
            var dispatcher = MvxSingleton<IMvxMainThreadDispatcher>.Instance;
            dispatcher?.RequestMainThreadAction(action);
        }

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            InvokeOnMainThread(() => base.OnPropertyChanged(e));
        }
```

But I don't get it why in my case it's not working as it suppose to, I mean with just regular `ObservableCollection`?

Is notyfier for `ObservableCollection` change creates another thread or what?

Comment: You have a threading problem. Probably caused by updating the Observable from a background thread. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18469700/2910520), [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/537) and [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1217)

Comment: @MatPag I saw it, but I tought like  call function in `dispatcher.RequestMainThreadAction` is enough, or it isn't?

Comment: It is enough, to use the dispatcher. However, your UI updates are in `Task.Run` a lot of places.

Comment: @Cheesebaron wellp even when I not using `Task.Run` wrapper, I got same picture :(

Comment: @Cheesebaron but I was just about updating the question, so, I found one thing there

Comment: Spent a full day trying to figure out this same exact issue and prefixing Mvx to ObservableCollection fixed it. Unbelievably stupid - welcome to the Xamarin experience. Little to no documentation, truck loads of bugs and issues.

Thank you sir I would up vote you 100,000 times if I could.

MvxObservableCollection is the answer.

Comment: @jazzmasterkc oh, thank you! Glad that this post was helpful! :D

Answer (score 0):

Not to steal the credit from @jazzmasterkc , but thought this needed to be posted as an answer. Using [MvxObservableCollection](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/ViewModels/MvxObservableCollection.cs) instead of ObservableCollection for list value binding fixes the issue as MvxObservableCollection invokes all PropertyChanged and CollectionChanged events on main thread.