# How to query what thread is running

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, observablecollection

In my program I add objects to an `ObservableCollection` from a background worker thread by utilizing the `AddOnUI` extension method used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091988/how-do-i-update-an-observablecollection-via-a-worker-thread).

The extension method that I am using:

```
public static void AddOnUI<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, T item)
{
    Action<T> addMethod = collection.Add;
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( addMethod, item );
}

...

collection.AddOnUI(new B());
```

This solution works perfectly for collection objects that get added from a background worker thread. However, when manually adding a collection object just on the UI thread with no background thread involved, **the collection does not populate in data, or in the View**. Is there a way to query what thread is active when calling an add method from an `ObservableCollection`?

Maybe do something like this?:

```
if(calling from background thread)
    collection.AddOnUI(new B());
else //Manually adding from UI Thread
    collection.Add(new B());
```

**Solution:**

My solution ended up being a lot similar to my pseudo code, which I really liked.

```
if(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground)
    collection.AddOnUI(new B());
else //Manually adding from UI Thread
    collection.Add(new B());
```

**Alternate Solution:**

`AddOnUI()` (Change `BeginInvoke` to `Invoke`):

```
public static void AddOnUI<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, T item)
{
    Action<T> addMethod = collection.Add;
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(addMethod, item);
}

collection.AddOnUI(new B());
```

Comment: Can you elaborate `It doesn't work`?

Comment: @RohitVats, sure. I've added my change in bold.

Comment: Anyhow it works for me in small sample. Collection gets updated for me.

Comment: With just `.AddOnUI()` for both situations? Or the solution I posted?

Comment: With just `.AddOnUI()`. Checking for thread is definitely a hacky solution. Have you tried `Invoke` in place of `BeginInvoke` in `AddOnUI()` method?

Comment: Just tried it, and you're right, it works much better. If you make an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking for thread is a hacky solution. You don't need it at all because framework internally make sure to dispatch the operation on correct thread.

Issue most likely is you are adding object `asynchronously (BeginInvoke)`. Add the object `synchronously (Invoke)` and you will see the item added immediately to the collection.

Replace

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(addMethod, item);
```

with

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(addMethod, item);
```

Comment: Technically @Aravol's solution works as well, but I chose to implement Rohit Vat's solution due to its  simplicity and better abstraction.

Answer (score 2):

[`System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentthread(v=vs.110).aspx) tells you what thread you're on, which can compare against the [`Dispatcher.Thread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.thread(v=vs.110).aspx) property.