# Binding to ItemsSource not working

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, binding

I have done the following in XAML

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="CursorLegendIC" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,0" Padding="0,0,0,-300">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Ellipse Width="8" Height="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,-16" Fill="{Binding SeriesColor, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}" />
                            <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="{Binding SeriesColor, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}" Text="{Binding SeriesName}"/>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="11" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,-3,0,4" Foreground="{Binding SeriesColor, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}" Text="{Binding YValue, StringFormat=\{0:0.000\}}" />
                            <TextBlock FontSize="11" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,-8,0,4" Foreground="{Binding SeriesColor, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}" Text="{Binding RenderableSeries.YAxisId}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>                        
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>                    
            </ItemsControl>
```

And I have set the data context accordingly:

```
void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        CursorLegendIC.DataContext = this.RolloverSeriesWithoutFirstData;
    }
```

And set the Observable collection property as public

```
public ObservableCollection<SeriesInfo> RolloverSeriesWithoutFirstData
    {
        get
        {
            ObservableCollection<SeriesInfo> Temp = rolloverModifier.SeriesData.SeriesInfo;
            return Temp;
        }
    }
```

But binding is still not working!

It seems to only take the binding at the first instance.

When data collection is later added, the binding changes does not seem to take effect.

Any help? Thanks

Comment: My guess is either, you are updating the collection asynchronously, which `INotifyCollectionChanged` does not support, or you are replacing the instance value of the property `RolloverSeriesWithoutFirstData`, without telling the binding that the value has changed (Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the event inside the set method)

Comment: If you update async you can either to this if on .NET 4.5 or higher: [How do I update an ObservableCollection via a worker thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14602121/1548864) or this if below [AsyncObservableCollection](https://gist.github.com/thomaslevesque/10023516) (NOTE: instance of the collection must be created on the UI thread)

Comment: Sorry.. Did not see you had a get only on the property.. Do you change the instance of `rolloverModifier.SeriesData.SeriesInfo`, or does it remain the same?

Comment: *"It seems to only take the binding at the first instance"*. Yes it is, unless you raise property changed notification which will tell binding to refresh it's value : [How to: Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229614%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: hi Nautious, yes the 'rolloverModifier.SeriesData.SeriesInfo' does changes

Comment: Funny i just noticed that only whenI inspect the data during debug, will the data change

Comment: Okay.. It's because `SeriesInfo` changes, but the owner of `RolloverSeriesWithoutFirstData` is not notified of this change. You need an event in `SeriesData` which tells the owner of `RolloverSeriesWithoutFirstData` that `SeriesInfo` has changed. Then the owner of `RolloverSeriesWithoutFirstData` need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to tell the binding that the `RolloverSeriesWithoutFirstData` has changed. Then ItemsSource will update.

Comment: I've posted an answer that takes care of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the instance (the entire collection) of the property `SeriesInfo` changes, without the owner of `RolloverSeriesWithoutFirstData` (lets call it MyWindow) is notified of the change. Either make your own event, or implemenet `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I've made an example with INPC:

```
class SeriesData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<SeriesInfo> _seriesInfo;
    public ObservableCollection<SeriesInfo> SeriesInfo
    {
        set{ SetProperty(ref _seriesInfo, value); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallermemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if(Equals(storage,value)) return false;
        storage = value;

        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if(handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        return true;
    }
}
```

In MyWindow you does this:

```
class MyWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<SeriesInfo> RolloverSeriesWithoutFirstData
    {
        get{ return rolloverModifier.SeriesData.SeriesInfo; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MyWindow()
    {
        // Get rolloverModifier
        rolloverModifier.SeriesData.PropertyChanged += SeriesDataPropertyChanged;
    }

    private void SeriesDataPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch(e.PropertyName)
        {
            case "SeriesInfo":
                RaisePropertyChanged("RolloverSeriesWithoutFirstData");
                break;
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if(handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Now `SeriesData` notifies it's listeners (our case `MyWindow`) that one of it's properties has changed value. `MyWindow` will then relay that notification to it's listeners (the bindings) that it's property: `RolloverSeriesWithoutFirstData` has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using MVVM pattern, you should remove the code behind and just bind to your ObservableCollection :

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="CursorLegendIC" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding RolloverSeriesWithoutFirstData}" Margin="0,0" Padding="0,0,0,-300">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Ellipse Width="8" Height="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,-16" Fill="{Binding SeriesColor, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="{Binding SeriesColor, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}" Text="{Binding SeriesName}"/>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="11" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,-3,0,4" Foreground="{Binding SeriesColor, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}" Text="{Binding YValue, StringFormat=\{0:0.000\}}" />
                        <TextBlock FontSize="11" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,-8,0,4" Foreground="{Binding SeriesColor, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}" Text="{Binding RenderableSeries.YAxisId}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>                        
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>                    
        </ItemsControl>
```

+Questions: what is *rolloverModifier* ? is *rolloverModifier.SeriesData.SeriesInfo* modified?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes it is. Just still not working

Comment: Your viewmodel implements INotifyPropertyChanged? If yes, can you try a manual refresh when the list is updated ? Like: OnPropertyChange("RolloverSeriesWithoutFirstData");

Comment: You can try also to add the viewmodel as static resource.

Comment: Actually my view model is the "public ObservableCollection<SeriesInfo> RolloverSeriesWithoutFirstData". It is part of the MainPage which is the UserControl

Answer (score 0):

You just need to implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) in the class that you defined your `RolloverSeriesWithoutFirstData` property in. As that property has no `setter`, you will have to manually raise the `NotifyPropertyChanged` event whenever you update the collection:

(pseudo code):

```
rolloverModifier.SeriesData.SeriesInfo = DataAccess.GetNewCollection();
NotifyPropertyChanged("RolloverSeriesWithoutFirstData");
```

Answer (score -2):

Change

```
CursorLegendIC.DataContext = this.RolloverSeriesWithoutFirstData
```

for

```
CursorLegendIC.ItemsSource= this.RolloverSeriesWithoutFirstData
```

Or as You can see in the above answer, remove code behind and use clear mvvm