# List Type update

Tags: c#, list, class, listview, arraylist

Have class

```
public class SignalRounding
    {
        public DateTime timee { get; set; }
        public string symbol { get; set; }
        public double price { get; set; }
        public double round { get; set; }
    }
```

Create List

```
public static List<SignalRounding> SignalR;
SignalR = new List<SignalRounding>();
ListView.ItemsSource = SignalR;
ListView.Items.Refresh();
```

Add some information

```
SignalR.Insert(0, new SignalRounding()
                {
                    timee = DateTime.Now,
                    symbol = symbol,
                    price = price,
                    round = round
                });
```

Update again

```
ListView.Items.Refresh();
```

Now displays List in my ListView, but I want to be displayed instead of the time the number of rows that were for a symbol in the past 10 minutes. Last added that satisfies the conditions should be the first in listview.

Comment: this question reads terribly.  I'm not really sure what you're asking

Comment: Are you trying to order the ListView by decreasing `timee`?

Comment: @Jonesopolis I want to display the number of rows for the last 10 minutes for a certain value

Comment: @Carl It is important for me to show only last 10 minutes for a certain value and the number of rows for the last 10 minutes

Comment: Are you still calling `ListView.Items.Refresh()`? As mentioned by @DrewJordan, don't name your objects/fields/properties the same as existing classes. You could have a problem with threading. I believe your actions on `ListView` must be run in the GUI thread, not a background thread. See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/a/2092036/1913277.

Comment: When I added When the worksheet from List to Ienumerable. For this reason it is possible is not displayed

Comment: The updates are performed in different threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this is what you're looking for... This takes in a list of your SignalR object, filters any that are older than 10 minutes, groups by symbol, and returns the list of aggregates sorted by the time, and then the quantity.

This assumes you have a ListView named `lv` (please, *please* don't name objects the same as their class).

Note: I added a call to `Thread.Sleep()` just to return some different timestamps in this example; that should obviously not be in your code otherwise.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static List<SignalRounding> SignalR;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SignalR = new List<SignalRounding>();

            var r = SignalR.Where(t => t.time >= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10))
            .GroupBy(g => g.symbol)
            .Select(s => new
            {
                Symbol = s.Key,
                Quantity = s.Count(),
                LastUpdated = s.Max(x => x.time),
                Price = s.Single(l => l.time == s.Max(x => x.time)).price,
                Round = s.Single(l => l.time == s.Max(x => x.time)).round
            })
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.LastUpdated)
            .ThenByDescending(x => x.Quantity);

            addStuff();

            lv.ItemsSource = r;
        }

        private void addStuff()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            {
                SignalR.Insert(0, new SignalRounding()
                {
                    time = DateTime.Now,
                    symbol = i % 10 == 0 ? "second" : i % 5 == 0 ? "third" : "first",
                    price = 0.25 * i,
                    round = i
                });
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
    }


    public class SignalRounding
    {
        public DateTime time { get; set; }
        public string symbol { get; set; }
        public double price { get; set; }
        public double round { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Your solution adds rows in the ListView, but there are no values. Here is a screenshot http://f5.s.qip.ru/twYEFNrp.png

Comment: If I add in the ListVIew - Count, LastUpdated - shows the line Symbol,Count, and Last updated, but does not show price and round

Comment: It's not meant to... the `Select` only pulls those three fields. If you could post your expected output, with some sample input, it would go a long way to narrowing down what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What you suggested is exactly what I need. Only need to add to display value of the last round and price

Comment: like this: `, price = s.Last( p => p.price)` but this code does not work

Comment: `.Select(s => new { symbol = s.Key, Quantity = s.Count(), LastUpdated = s.Max(x => x.timee), price = s.Last( p => p.price), round = s.Last(p => p.round)})`

Comment: I just edited it to add price and round from the most recent record, see if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I originally wanted. Sorry for the tediousness and my bad English)

Comment: Cheers! Next time, if along with your code you can provide sample data, and show what you want the result to look like, it will be a lot easier to help you. Good luck!

Comment: when i click right mouse on item in ListView, i get `SelectedItems[0]` and when i convert it to `(SignalRounding)ListView.SelectedItems[0]` i get error like this: http://f2.s.qip.ru/twYEFNup.png fails to convert, do not know why?

Comment: <sigh> I can't read [Russian?] but it's because `Select` returns an anonymous type, which isn't a `SignalRounding` and cannot convert to a `SignalRounding`. You're not selecting a `SignalRounding`, you're selecting a couple of properties from a specific one, and also a quantity.

Comment: Yes, russian) How i can get symbol value, from selected item of ListView ?

Comment: Yes, russian) How i can get symbol value, from selected item of ListView ?

Comment: As @DrewJordan said, you're selecting an anonymous type that can't be cast to `SignalRounding`. I suggest you create a new class similar to `SignalRounding` but with the properties you really need (`Symbol`, `Quantity`, `LastUpdated`, `Price`, `Round`) and use this instead of the anonymous type. This will allow you to access the properties you need.

Comment: @Carl Thanks, I think I fix mistake

Comment: @Carl i have new bug:`Collection was modified; the operation cannot be performed enumerating.` Tried to use the code in `try-catch`, but the error still appears

Comment: for help with a new issue, please post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a naive solution, based on what I understand of your question. Replace your `ItemsSource` with a Linq expression like the one below to restrict and sort.

```
using System.Linq;

ListView.ItemsSource = SignalR.OrderByDescending(s => s.timee).Where(s => (DateTime.Now - s.timee).TotalMinutes < 10);
```

There will be some performance and scalability issues to consider if your list is going to get very long.

If you want to show the number of rows that were added for each symbol in the last 10 minutes, it's a bit different and you might need to edit your GUI to handle the output which is a list of [anonymous objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) with properties called `Symbol`, `Count` and `LastAdded`. If it's clearer for you, you could create a class called `SymbolCounter` and use that instead of the anonymous class.

```
ListView.ItemsSource = SignalR.Where(s => (DateTime.Now - s.timee).TotalMinutes < 10).GroupBy(s => s.symbol, (key, values) => new {Symbol = key, Count = values.Count(), LastAdded = values.Max(s => s.timee)});
```

If you want to filter so that only the rows for a given symbol value are shown, just use `SignalR.Where(s => s.symbol == "AAPL")....`.

You can find documentation for many Linq extension methods [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable_methods(v=vs.110).aspx). These can be chained and applied to your initial list. There are plenty of tutorials about this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, please tell me how to improve this solution. For example, if there are no duplicate rows, where the symbol = "AAPL" for example?

Comment: Need to class SignalRounding add Count ?

Comment: No, you don't need to add a `Count` property to `SignalRounding`. In that example, `ItemsSource` is no longer a list of `SignalR` objects but a list of anonymous objects with slightly different properties. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Don't know why, but if you write code like this `List.ItemsSource = SignalR;` List is updated,  but if I'll add.Where -  List is not updated

Comment: If I add in the ListVIew this columns - Count , LastAdded  - shows the line Symbol,Count, and Last LastAdded , but does not show price and round

Comment: when i click right mouse on item in ListView, i get SelectedItems[0] and when i convert it to (SignalRounding)ListView.SelectedItems[0] i get error like this: f2.s.qip.ru/twYEFNup.png fails to convert, do not know why?

Comment: See comments on @DrewJordan's answer.