# updating an async ObservableCollection with progress

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, observablecollection

My problem is that my task is changing an observable collection that is data-bound to a UI element.
my task will report progress and this data will be updated to the ui via the `observable collection`:

```
async private void getProductData()
{
    await Task.Run(() => getTableDataFromDb(new Progress<string>(
       data => _prc.Add(new ProductList() { Taxe = data })
       ), "List"));
}
private void getTableDataFromDb(IProgress<string> progress, string tabelName)
{
   //simple exemple
   for(var i =0; i < 100; i++)
     progress.Report( "test"+i);
}
```

if i run this code i get this error:

> This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its
>   SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.

How can i access the main thread to update this collections?
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091988/how-do-i-update-an-observablecollection-via-a-worker-thread

Comment: my app is using async-await not backgroundworker, thanks

Comment: It's the same problem...collection being changed on a background thread.

Comment: @MikeMarynowski: your link is very useful and definitely relevant to the _general_ scenario. However, in this case the OP had already implemented what they thought should address the cross-thread issue -- the `Progress<T>` class is designed for that very purpose and is a great way to handle it using the `async`/`await` pattern. It's just that the implementation wasn't quite right initially, and wasn't working as expected.

Comment: Ohhh, sorry, I thought progress was just a class in this project. Never heard of this before, good to know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating the `Progress<string>` object in the wrong thread. It's being created in the same worker thread that's actually doing the work, which means it doesn't capture the correct `SynchronizationContext` object to marshal the work back to the thread you want.

Instead, you want something like this:

```
async private void getProductData()
{
    IProgress<string> progress = new Progress<string>(
       data => _prc.Add(new ProductList() { Taxe = data }));

    await Task.Run(() => getTableDataFromDb(progress, "List"));
}
```

That will create the `Progress<string>` object in the thread that calls the `getProductData()`, which is presumably your UI thread. Then when the `IProgress<string>.Report()` method is called, the delegate invocation will be marshalled back to the UI thread as intended.