# OxyPlot graphic doesn't update

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I'm developing a WPF app with C#, .NET Framework 4.7. and Oxyplot 1.0.

I'm trying to update the graphic at runtime, but it doesn't do anything.

I have tried to use `ObsevableCollection` and `InvalidateFlag` but without success.

This is the XAML:

```
<oxy:Plot Title="{Binding Title}" InvalidateFlag="{Binding InvalidateFlag}">
    <oxy:Plot.Series>
        <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding BestFitness}"/>
        <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding WorstFitness}"/>
        <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding AverageFitness}"/>
    </oxy:Plot.Series>
</oxy:Plot>
```

And this is the view model:

```
public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private int count;
    private int _invalidateFlag;

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int InvalidateFlag
    {
        get { return _invalidateFlag; }
        set
        {
            _invalidateFlag = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("InvalidateFlag");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<DataPoint> BestFitness { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<DataPoint> WorstFitness { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<DataPoint> AverageFitness { get; set; }

    public ICommand StartCommand
    {
        get { return new DelegateCommand(Start); }
    }

    public ICommand RefereshCommand
    {
        get { return new DelegateCommand(Refresh); }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.Title = "Example 2";
        this.BestFitness = new ObservableCollection<DataPoint>
        {
            new DataPoint(0, 4),
            new DataPoint(10, 13),
            new DataPoint(20, 15),
            new DataPoint(30, 16),
            new DataPoint(40, 12),
            new DataPoint(50, 12)
        };
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

        Program program = new Program(rnd);

        program.Algorithm.EvolutionEnded += Algorithm_EvolutionEnded;

        count = 0;
        this.BestFitness = new ObservableCollection<DataPoint>();
        this.WorstFitness = new ObservableCollection<DataPoint>();
        this.AverageFitness = new ObservableCollection<DataPoint>();

        Task.Run(() => program.Run(null));
    }

    private void Refresh()
    {
        this.BestFitness.Clear();
    }

    private void Algorithm_EvolutionEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EvolutionEndedEventArgs args = (EvolutionEndedEventArgs)e;

        BestFitness.Add(new DataPoint(count, args.BestFitness));
        WorstFitness.Add(new DataPoint(count, args.WorstFitness));
        AverageFitness.Add(new DataPoint(count, args.AverageFitness));

        InvalidateFlag++;
    }
}
```

Do I need to do anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
this.BestFitness = new ObservableCollection<DataPoint>();
...
```

you are replacing the complete `ItemsSource` of the plot. Since there is no notification of the view by calling `RaisePropertyChangedEvent` afterwards, the bound plot will not recognize the change and the plot will not update it's points.

There are two possible solutions:

**1. Use the INotifyPropertychanged** by calling `RaisePropertyChangedEvent` after replacing the collection. Therefore

```
public ObservableCollection<DataPoint> BestFitness { get; set; }
```

should be extended to

```
private ObservableCollection<DataPoint> _BestFitness;
public ObservableCollection<DataPoint> BestFintess
{
    get
    {
        return _BestFitness;
    }
    private set
    {
        _BestFitness = value;
        RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(BestFintess));
    }
}
```

**2. Don't replace the whole ObservableCollection.** Simply clear the existing collections and use them again. This means use

```
this.BestFitniss.Clear();
```

instead of

```
this.BestFitness = new ObservableCollection<DataPoint>();
```

Both solutions notifying the view about changes and the plot will update it's points without using the `InvalidateFlag`.

Note that it is required to use the UI thread to change the items of an `ObservableCollection` as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091988/how-do-i-update-an-observablecollection-via-a-worker-thread). Since you are using an other thread to add values invoking the UI like

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        BestFitness.Add(new DataPoint(count, args.BestFitness));
    });
```

is required.

Comment: I've done what you said, and now I get the exception `This type of CollectionView does not support changes to the SourceCollection of a subprocess other than the Dispatcher thread.` when I do `BestFitness.Add(new DataPoint(count, args.BestFitness));`.

Comment: This is because you are changing the `ObservableCollection` out of a non UI thread. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091988/how-do-i-update-an-observablecollection-via-a-worker-thread) and invoke your UI thread like `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { BestFitness.Add(new DataPoint(count, args.BestFitness)); });`

Comment: I am doing this, but sometimes I got exception `This PlotModel is already in use by some other PlotView control.` from OxyPlot: `UIItems.Clear();

   DataLoaderService.OnDataLoaded += (index, uiItem) =>
   {
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
     UIItems.Insert(index, uiItem);
    }));
   };

// Load data`

Comment: Yeah, I know that error, but I am wondering why it is thrown in my case (very similar to the one provided into the solution answer) and at the second iteration rather than the first

Answer (score 0):

I have created this small example to show how to update the graphic at runtime. I hope it helps!

ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Timers;
using OxyPlot;
using OxyPlot.Series;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class MainViewModel
    {
        private LineSeries lineSeries;
        private int count;

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            this.MyModel = new PlotModel { Title = "Example 1" };
            //this.MyModel.Series.Add(new FunctionSeries(Math.Cos, 0, 10, 0.1, "cos(x)"));
            //this.MyModel.Series.Add(new FunctionSeries(Math.Sin, 0, 10, 0.1, "sin(x)"));

            lineSeries = new LineSeries();
            lineSeries.LineStyle = LineStyle.Solid;
            lineSeries.StrokeThickness = 2.0;
            lineSeries.Color = OxyColor.FromRgb(0, 0, 0);

            this.MyModel.Series.Add(lineSeries);

            Timer timer = new Timer(1000);
            timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
            timer.Start();

            count = 0;
        }

        private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            lineSeries.Points.Add(new DataPoint(count, Math.Pow(count, 2)));
            this.MyModel.InvalidatePlot(true);

            count++;
        }

        public PlotModel MyModel { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf" x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding MyModel}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```