# .NET Core and Cross-thread Dispatching

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, mvvm-light

I'm working on porting a large .NET Framework application to .NET Core. The application uses WPF for the UI layer and utilizes **MVVM Light** (MvvmLightLibsStd10) for implementing MVVM architecture.

One of the problems I'm currently facing is with cross-thread UI updates. In the Framework version I was using `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform` library to get access to `DispatcherHelper` which contains an easy-to- use `DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI()` function to disptach property change notifications.

Now this `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform` library is available in `net45` folder in the NuGet package, but not in `netstandard1.0` folder, which gives me a hint that this lib might be platform (Windows?)-specific and therefore not suitable for .net core project.

Is it advisable to use this lib? If not, what would be the proper way of raising property change notifications in a thread-safe manner?

Update: Just found that this is one of the requested features on github:

https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/pull/79

Comment: Your question is too broad at best, opinion-based at worst. That said, for basic non-collection properties, you should not need any extra code at all, as WPF handles cross-thread notification for `INotifyPropertyChanged` implicitly. WPF also has built-in handling for collection-changed notifications, but this requires some initial setup in your code to opt-in to the feature.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: I have had mixed results in the past. Sometimes UI gets updated cleanly without any thread-handling; sometimes it throws cross-thread marshaling exception, especially when changing props in timer tick events. I thought it would be safe to always do it through `DispatchHelper`.

Comment: *WPF also has built-in handling for collection-changed notifications, but this requires some initial setup in your code to opt-in to the feature.* Any links/hints in this direction?

Comment: _"I thought it would be safe to always do it through DispatchHelper"_ -- yes, that's true. Assuming done correctly, there's never any harm in explicitly ensuring you're on the right thread, even if the framework would do it for you anyway. _"Any links/hints in this direction?"_ -- have you searched Stack Overflow for topics related to `INotifyCollectionChanged` in WPF? Anyway, you could start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091988/how-do-i-update-an-observablecollection-via-a-worker-thread

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Thanks. Jon's answer on that page appears very helfpul. Also, I later found that MVVM Light provides one version of `Platform` library for each platform including android, xamarin and .netfx. I'll see if I can avoid that lib altogether.