# ObservableCollection AddRange in async Task

Tags: wpf, async-await, task, observablecollection

Hi I want to use the ObservableCollection (AddRange) in async Task but i get NotSupportedException

```
private ObservableCollection<CoronavirusCountry> _data = new ObservableCollection<CoronavirusCountry>();
        public ObservableCollection<CoronavirusCountry> data
        {
            get => _data;
            set => SetProperty(ref _data, value);
        }

Task.Run(async()=>{
   APIService service = new APIService();
            data.AddRange(await service.GetTopCases());
            Status = "Updated " + DateTime.Now;

});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I update an ObservableCollection via a worker thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091988/how-do-i-update-an-observablecollection-via-a-worker-thread)

Comment: @PeterDuniho thank you, How can I use this extension with addrange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which `AddRange` method you are referring to, because ObservableCollection doesn't have that out of the box.

Anyway - assuming you wrote an extension method - it has to be called in the UI thread, so running a Task doesn't make sense.

The awaitable method shown below should be sufficient. It would await the asynchronous service call, and update the collection in the main thread.

```
public async Task UpdateData()
{
    var service = new APIService();
    var newData = await service.GetTopCases();

    Data.AddRange(newData); // use proper naming!

    Status = "Updated " + DateTime.Now;
}
```

---

In order to call and await the above method, you could have an async Loaded event handler like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    viewModel = new ViewModel();

    Loaded += async (s, e) => await viewModel.UpdateData();
}
```

Comment: thank you but i need to call this method in ctor, and i heard that if i call `UpdateData().Wait() ` Causes deadblock That's why I want to execute the code within the task

Comment: You can't call an awaitable method in a constructor - and the Task you were creating must also be awaited. If you are referring to the constructor of a UI element, e.g. a Window or UserControl, call it in an async Loaded event handler.

Comment: my ctor is in viewmodel (prism mvvm)