# System.NotSupportedException: 'This type of Collection view does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread ...'

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, observablecollection, notsupportedexception

**Edit:** My question is not answered by related threads because I want to **avoid adding boilerplate every time I need to interact with an Observable Collection.**

I **do not** need the application to be responsive while my loading operation plays out. What I need, really, is for one window (the loading popup) to animate and update even when the main window is frozen. I would have thought this was simple.

---

I have a 3D scene containing a hierarchy of 3D objects. Some objects are serialised as Json, and I have a button on these objects called 'Export And Reimport', which serialises and reloads that object.

This process often involves rebuilding the 3D hierarchy to match the re-imported data. It can be time consuming.

I want to show a loading popup to assure the user that the program is still functioning. I've investigated a few ways of doing this, including BackgroundWorkers:

```
public BackgroundWorker _backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

public void ExportAndReimport()
{
    OpenLoadingWindow("Exporting and Reimporting ");
    
    _backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler((s, e) =>
    {
        Export();
        Import();
    });
    
    _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler((s, e) =>
    {
        CloseLoadingWindow();
    });
    
    _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

and async operations:

```
public async Task ExportAndReimport()
{
    OpenLoadingWindow("Exporting and Reimporting ");
    
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Export();
        Import();
        CloseLoadingWindow();
    });
}
```

In both cases, the problem is the same: my 3D objects contain many `ObservableCollection`s (since the UI has to represent their properties, among other things). For example, a given object's **Children** property, which of course is re-populated on reloading the object. I'm not able to make changes to an `ObservableCollection` from a thread different to the one it was created on.

I just want to freeze input while the load is happening, and show an animated window (ideally, but not necessarily, with a progress bar). What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14602121/1136211

Comment: @Clemens while this is an option, it involves adding a lot of boilerplate across all my uses of ObservableCollection, plus requiring other coders to magically know they need to do the same in the future.

Is there really nothing more simple? All I want is for one window to update while another does not.

Comment: You have seen the other option with using the UI thread's Dispatcher?

Comment: That also seems to involve just changing the way i interact with ObservableCollections in all cases, across my entire codebase. Same problem.