# Event Receiver - How to update fields from List A based on List B

Tags: visual-studio, list, visual-studio-2013, event-receiver, eventreceiver

I'm new to Event Receivers and I never have done one. Here is my situation, I have 2 lists. First list contains fields: Software Name, Quantity, Used, Available, and COUNT [Software Name: (Count Related)] from second list. Second list contains field: Software Name (Lookup from first list). How do I calculate and update fields Used and Available in the first list when a new item is added or updated in the second list? Any examples or links are really appreciated

Regards,

Fernando

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If yes, post it and then ask what you are doing wrong. If not, first try it out yourself.

Comment: Use an ObservableCollection. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785019/listt-firing-event-on-change

Comment: Like I said, I'm new and I have never done an event receiver but so far what i have is this for the ItemAdded but I don't know how to updates the other fields in the other list.

Comment: Here is my code for the ItemAdded: base.ItemAdded(properties); 
try
{
base.EventFiringEnabled = false; 
using (SPSite site = properties.OpenSite()) 
{
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb()) 
{
SPList list = web.Lists["License Tracking"]; 
SPItem item = list.Items.Add(); 
item["Title"] = properties.ListItem["Title"]; 
item.Update(); 
}
}
}