# Events: How to keep eye on List Object properties

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a list `activeAcountList` of `object` (`ActiveAccount`).

```
List<ActiveAccount> activeAcountList = new List<ActiveAccount>();
```

The object/ActiveAccount some props/info are Key, Name, Account, Amount, Source and some more properties.

I don't own this object, its been owned by a 3rd party and i am using an event given by them, that fires when ever 
something changes or added to the list. Below is the event method that get fires every time when something added or
updated and i am using same event for populating my `activeAcountList`

```
Private void GetAccountList(ActiveAccount activeAccountData)
{
    if(!activeAcountList.Contains(activeAccountData.Key))
    {
        activeAcountList.Add(activeAccountData);
    }
    else
    {
        activeAcountList[activeAccountData.Key] = activeAccountData;
    }
}
```

Now my question is, is there any way i can attach an event that fires every time when 'Amount' changes? Or
if i can keep eye on any property and when ever it changes this event fires? Just keep in mind i dont own this object so i can not do any
thing with ActiveAccount class.

Comment: hmm which one class? ActiveAccount? If Yes, its not my class i dont have code for it.

Comment: So, `GetAccountList` is called when there is a change.  I think you have a typo, why are you using `activeAccountData` as some kind of dictionary? I think you mean `activeAcountList`, right? Even with that, why are you changing the value in that list/dictionary? Do you get a different `ActiveAccount` instance when `GetAccountList` is invoked? if it is the same instance, you don't have to update the dictionary.

Comment: @YacoubMassad Yes Yacoub , its like data might be updated some where else by some body else, so whenever data is updated i am updating my own list. And no its not a type its activeAccountData which is dictionary..

Comment: This is confusing. Please review this line again: `activeAccountData[activeAccountData.Key] = activeAccountData`. Are you sure it is correct?

Comment: Oops i didn't pay attention to else part you are right ma Bad.. its activeAcountList[activeAccountData.Key] = activeAccountData;

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work. Please check it
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785019/listt-firing-event-on-change)

Comment: i am already aware of ObservableCollection. Its not telling me What Property has been changed. i mean it will give me Whole Object with previous prop and Update Whole Object with new prop. I am not getting an Individual prop e.g; if Amount has been update i need to know Amount prop has been updated to this val... i hope it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

`System.ComponentModel.BindingList<T>` can be one option. [From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx)

`BindingList<T>` have `ListChanged` event which fired when properties of item in the list are changed.
It fires also when items added or removed from the list

[BindingList.ListChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132742(v=vs.110).aspx)

Of course, for item's changes to be notified type of the item need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface

Comment: but i don't own the ActiveAccount class that contains each individual item so i can't implement INotifyPropertyChanged on ActiveAccount porperteis. Is there any way i can use INotifyPropertyChanged interface on list object items or something along these lines?

Comment: You can create your own "ViewModel" which implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and use `ActiveAccount` instance as model.