# How to disable a button if there is no items in DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `DataGrid` which bound a `List<T>`, this is the structure:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid"
          ItemSource="{Binding myList}" />
```

I want enable a button only if there is items `myDataGrid`, actually I'm able to enable the button only if the user have selected an item in this way:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=myDataGrid}" Value="{x:Null}">       
                     <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".5" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
   </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

how can I do that?

Comment: How are they selecting an item if there are none?

Answer (score 2):

You could make the collection you're binding an observablecollection.
Then use a datatrigger which checks count on that.

```
<Button Content="SomeButton">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding myObservableCollection.Count}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give me a name to the button:

```
<Button x:Name="myBTN"> ...
```

Make a method that do the check and enable or disable the button:

```
void CheckList()
{
    if(list.Count == 0)
    {
        myBTN.IsEnabled = false;
    }
    else
        myBTN.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

And now everytime you call myList.add() or myList.remove(), call the CheckList() method.

Or check this: 
[How to handle add to list event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299920/how-to-handle-add-to-list-event)
Make a new class inheriting from List, and add an event handler to Add and Remove.

Answer (score 0):

DataGrid has boolean `HasItems` property. Bind IsEnabled directly.

`<Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />` repeats the default and can be omitted.

And finally since button IsEnabled was set via Binding, a Trigger can be used instead of DataTrigger:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding Path=HasItems, ElementName=myDataGrid}">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".5" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
   </Button.Style>
</Button>
```