# Does the method List<T>.Remove() call the method Dispose() from the removing object?

Tags: c#

I have several objects in collection List. I need to know whether the method Dispose() is called when objects are removing from collection? If not, whether is there some way to call it when objects are
being removed?

Comment: No, `Dispose()` is not called.

Comment: Why would you expect that removing an item from a list would destroy the item?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle add to list event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299920/how-to-handle-add-to-list-event)

Comment: *is there some way to call it when objects are being removed?* - wrap the list or subclass Collection<T> to create a collection for your objects, that ensures Dispose is called on the item removed. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376203/inheriting-from-listt

Comment: @CaiusJard I have modified his question, please answer

Comment: @viveknuna I rolled back your edit; it adds words that the original author did not write. Please acquaint yourself with what is, and is not acceptable when editing a question

Comment: @CaiusJard no problem, but can you please answer my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to create your own collection class who manage disposing. Actualy list & collection has nothing to do with object lifetime.

```
public class AutoDisposeList<T> : IList<T> where T : IDisposable
{
    public void Add(T item)
    {
         base.Add(item);
    }
    
    public void RemoveAndDispose(T item)
    {
        base.Remove(item);
        item.Dispose();
    }
    
}
```